# WordPress $_POST is empty in admin-post.php request

Tags: php, wordpress, angular, angular6

I'm using `/wp-admin/admin-post.php` as an endpoint to receive ajax post requests from my Angular app. Here is the setup to register the endpoint in my wordpress plugin:

```
function _admin_post_myaction() {
    // Just to see what's there
    wp_send_json( array(
        '$_POST' => $_POST,
        '$_GET' => $_GET,
        '$_REQUEST' => $_REQUEST
    ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_post_myaction', '_admin_post_myaction' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_myaction', '_admin_post_myaction' );
```

In Angular, I am sending a posts request using HttpClient:

```
this.http
  .post(this.config.adminURL + '?action=order_ingredients', {
    action: 'order_ingredients',
    data: this.data
  })
  .subscribe({
    next: value => {
      console.log('Next', value);
    },
    error: err => {
      console.error('Error', err);
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log('Complete');
    }
  });
```

I get the following result:

```
{action: "myaction", $_POST: [], $_REQUEST: {action: "myaction"}
```

It looks like the POST data is getting erased by WordPress at some point before it gets to the admin-post action. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you posting url_encoded form values from angular?  By default it would post a json object which would be the request body, not the post object.

Comment: @user1119648 Just a raw JSON object

Comment: That won't show up in a $_POST super global.  You have to json_decode the request body with something like `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: That works! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the content of the request and json decode it using something like:

`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`